# Parsing floats in Rust from Fortran formats

Tags: floating-point, rust

I'm rewriting a C++ parser in Rust for a legacy ASCII data format. Real number values in this format are permitted to be stored in any Fortran recognized format. Unfortunately, Fortran recognizes some formats not recognized by Rust (or most other languages). For example, the value 101.01 might be represented as

- 101.01
- 1.0101E2
- 101.01e0
- 101.01D0
- 101.01d0
- 101.01+0
- 1010.1-1

The first three are all natively recognized by Rust. The remaining four pose a challenge. In C++, we use the following routine to parse these values:

```
double parse(const std::string& s){
  char* p;
  const double significand = strtod(&s[0], &p);
  const long exponent = (*p == '\0') ? 
                          0 : isalpha(*p) ?
                            strtol(p+1, nullptr) :
                              strtol(p, nullptr);
  return significand * pow(10, exponent);
}
```

After reviewing the Rust documentation, it doesn't appear that the standard library offers partial string parsing in the vein of `strtod` and `strtol`. I'd like to avoid taking multiple passes over the string or using regular expressions for performance reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would have been a comment to Veedrac's answer, but it got a bit long for a comment.

As Veedrac explains, parsing floats accurately is **hard**. The implementation in the standard library is completely accurate and reasonably well optimized. In particular, it's not *much* slower than the naive inaccurate algorithm for most inputs where the naive algorithm works. You should use it. Full disclaimer: I wrote it.

Where I disagree with Veedrac is how to proceed if you want to reuse that code. Ripping it out from the standard library is a bad idea. It's huge, about 2.5k lines of code, and it still changes/is improved occasionally — although rarely and mostly in very minor ways. But one day I'll find the time to rewrite the slow path to be better and faster, promised. **If** you rip out this code, you would have to take the `core::num::dec2flt` module and modify the `parse` submodule to recognize other exponents. Of course then you won't automatically benefit from future improvements, which is a shame if you're interested in performance.

The sanest way would be translate the other formats to the format supported by Rust. If it's a `d`, `D` or a bare `+` you can simply replace it with an `e` and pass it on to string . Only in the case `1010.1-1` you will need to insert an `e` and shift the exponent part of the string. This should not cost much performance. Float strings are short (at most 20 or so bytes, often much less) and the actual conversion work does a good chunk of work per byte. This is true for your C++ code as well, because [`strtod` is accurate in glibc too](http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-glibc-strtod-works/). Or at least it's trying to be, it can't fix the ad hoc algorithm built around it. In any case, it is trying to .

Another possibility is to use FFI to call C's `strtod`. Use the [libc crate](https://crates.io/crates/libc) and call `libc::strtod`. This requires some contortions to translate from `&str` to raw pointers to `c_char`, and it will handle interior 0 bytes badly, but the code you show is not terribly robust anyway. This would allow you to translate your algorithm to Rust with identical performance and semantics and (in)accuracy.

Comment: I mentioned the translating idea but didn't press it since apmccartney explicitly said it's too slow. I object to the claim that "it's not *much* slower than the naive inaccurate algorithm"; I just whipped up a quick inaccurate test parser and it's 5x as fast on "33.1453326" (and a few other test cases). If he's worried about speed here (assuming that he's not just saying it for the sake of it), it's hardly equivocal. Adding an *extra* parse on top of that is just going to exacerbate the difference, as would a little bit of performance tuning.

Comment: For the moment, I've implemented the "sanest way" suggested by delnan (if only in the hope data will improve in coming years). If this approach proves too expensive, I will likely implement the strategy you suggested in the comments to your response, Veedrac.

Comment: @Veedrac From my own benchmarks vs. the old implementation in the standard library (a few months ago), I expected something around 2x as fast for that class of inputs. 5x surprises me, could you put your code in a gist so I can study it?

Comment: @delnan It's not pretty (every time I tried to make it pretty, it ended up slower), but [I've finished it up for you](https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/dbb0c07994bc7882098e). I don't know how correct it is, since I've barely got tests for it, but it seems to mostly work.

Answer (score 2):

Your example in C++ does not give perfectly accurate results, but Rust's float parsing [is intended to be perfectly accurate, and as such has slower parsing than you might need](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27307).

If you implement approximate parsing manually, it will likely come out a faster than any other technique available. A quick test I did locally suggests you can easily get a factor of 5 over the performance of the standard library's `parse` method.

If you rather wish to have exact parsing, your C++ code is insufficient. A pre-parse (eg. with Regex) is likely the easiest way to do this, but alternatively you can rip out the code from the standard library and modify that.

Comment: I appreciate the warning! 

I understood the algorithm I posted can introduce error; That said, I have the good fortune of working with data representing measurements where seven digits of precision is considered quite good. Any introduced error was not observed during our testing.

Comment: Thank you for a reference to the github commit as well. It made for interesting reading.

Comment: If you've only got 7 digits of precision and need speed, you'd be fine with just parsing the value into an `i64` and multiplying by a cached power of 10 (calculate the exponent by adding the decimal place to the explicit one). That should be blazingly fast.

Comment: I've bookmarked this response for future reference. 

The application is intended for real time processing, but we're still in the very early stages of testing under load. If it turns out the file parsing is a bottleneck, I'll implement this method for comparison.

Comment: We ended up using the technique you described in the comments here. Thanks again!